# Using scipy optimize for MLE estimate and curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, mle

I randomly generated 1000 data points using the weights I know are true for the normal distribution. Now I am trying to minimize the -log likelihood function to estimate the values of sig^2 and the weights. I sort of get the process conceptually, but when I try to code it I'm just lost.

This is my model:

```
p(y|x, w, sig^2) = N(y|w0+w1x+...+wnx^n, sig^2)
```

I've been googling for a while now and I've learned the scipy.stats.optimize.minimize function is good for this, but I can't get it to work right. Every solution I have tried has worked for the example I got the solution from, but I'm unable to extrapolate it to my problem.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1000, num=1000)
data = []
for y in x:
        data.append(np.polyval([.5, 1, 3], y))

#plot to confirm I do have a normal distribution...
data.sort()
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(data, np.mean(data), np.std(data))
plt.plot(test, pdf)
plt.show()

#This is where I am stuck.
logLik = -np.sum(stats.norm.logpdf(data, loc=??, scale=??))
```

I have found that the equation error(**w**) = .5*sum(poly(x_n, **w**) - y_n)^2 is relevant for minimizing the error of the weights, which therefore maximizes my likelihood for the weights, but I don't understand how to code this... I have found a similar relationship for sig^2, but have the same problem. Can somebody clarify how to do this to help my curve fitting? Maybe go as far to post psuedo code I can use?

Comment: What is `test` ? Can you edit your question to provide an example of `test` that we can use? Also, what is your desired output? Values for the weights and sigma that maximize the likelihood?

Comment: Ah test was an older list I was using that I replaced with data, it was a typo in the SO code. Yes, I am trying to find values for the weights and sigma that maximize the likelihood.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, implementing likelihood fitting with `minimize` is tricky, I spend a lot of time on it. Which is why I wrapped it. If I may shamelessly plug my own package [`symfit`](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#likelihood), your problem can be solved by doing something like this:

```
from symfit import Parameter, Variable, Likelihood, exp
import numpy as np

# Define the model for an exponential distribution
beta = Parameter()
x = Variable()
model = (1 / beta) * exp(-x / beta)

# Draw 100 samples from an exponential distribution with beta=5.5
data = np.random.exponential(5.5, 100)

# Do the fitting!
fit = Likelihood(model, data)
fit_result = fit.execute()
```

I have to admit I don't exactly understand your distribution, since I don't understand the role of your `w`, but perhaps with this code as an example, you'll know how to adapt it.

If not, let me know the full mathematical equation of your model so I can help you further.

For more info check the [docs](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#likelihood). (For a more technical description of what happens under the hood, read [here](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_docs.html#symfit.core.fit.Likelihood) and [here](http://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/likelihood.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an issue with your setup. With maximum likelihood, you obtain the parameters that maximize the probability of observing your data (given a certain model). Your model seems to be:

[image]

where epsilon is N(0, sigma).

So you maximize it:

[image]

or equivalently take logs to get:

[image]

The f in this case is the log-normal probability density function which you can get with `stats.norm.logpdf`. You should then use `scipy.minimize` to maximize an expression that will be the summation of  `stats.norm.logpdf` evaluated at each of the i points, from 1 to your sample size.

If I've understood you correctly, your code is missing having a `y` vector plus an `x` vector! Show us a sample of those vectors and I can update my answer to include a sample code for estimating MLE with that date.